# getting stuck while using Neuralnet package

Tags: r

I am trying to train a model by taking the following data set 
https://github.com/merwan/ml-class/tree/master/mlclass-ex4/ex4data1.mat  Note: this is a 7MB file.

But i am getting stuck and not getting the answer after waiting for long time.Can some one suggest me modifications in my code ?

```
raw_data <- readMat('C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/ml-class-master/ml-class-master/mlclass-ex4/ex4data1.mat');
X <- unlist(raw_data['X']);
X <- matrix(X, nrow=5000)
y <-unlist(raw_data['y'])
Y <- matrix(y, nrow=5000)
mydata<-as.data.frame(X);
mydata$Y<-Y;
n<-names(mydata)[1:400]
fm <- paste("Y ~", paste(n, collapse="+"))
fm <- as.formula(fm)
m<-neuralnet(fm,data=mydata,hidden=25,stepmax=1e6,rep=50)
```

Comment: neural nets can long for a very very long time with large data, how long are you waiting.

Comment: more than 3 hours . earlier i got Warning message:
algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax .

Comment: I haven't looked at the size of the whole dataset, but you can simply say `Y ~ .`. Instead of `fm <- paste("Y ~", paste(n, collapse="+"))`.
 I would suggest trying that to see if you can save yourself a few lines.
Try running the neural net with a smaller subset (under 100 sample) and see if you can run without errors.

Comment: Which packages are 'readMat' and 'neuralnet' from?

Comment: neuralnet is excellent for smaller dataset .

Comment: This is how i imported both readmat and neuralnet  packages  install.packages('neuralnet',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org');
 library(neuralnet)
 install.packages('R.matlab',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org');
 library(R.matlab)

Comment: If some one gets the answer then  apply the compute() and cor() function by taking mydata[1:400],m as input for compute and m$net.result,mydata[Y] as input for cor() function . Please tell me what was the value for cor()  function ? I Also  want the weights after training neural network .

Comment: @ZDavies apparently this `neuralnet` package doesn't support `y~.` format of including all the variables.

Comment: @raj the `rep` argument is repeating the training 50 times. reduce that to 1 or 2 and check if that works. Regarding neural net training, doing it via caret and `nnet` is pretty fast.

Comment: @Frash ah thats disappointing then. I also suggest using caret. You can try many of the other neural network packages. E.g. nnet.

Comment: Thank you Frash and Davies . By nnnet via caret way the corelation between the actual output and predicted value is 0.77 . Any suggestions to improve the corelation ? In case of neural net by increasing the hidden value we can improve the performance of model . Similarly i want to improve the model performance of nnet .

Comment: What i mean is                                                                                     "mynnetfit <- train(Y ~ ., data = MyData, method = "nnet", .......)"                                                                                                           Here which parameter works similar to hidden in neuralnet

Comment: I even got Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Resample01: size=3, decay=0e+00 Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) : too many (1207) weights
I also want to see weights but i 
model$wts is giving me NULL

Comment: > model

5000 samples
 400 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  size  decay  RMSE      Rsquared   RMSE SD     Rsquared SD
  1     0e+00  2.332468  0.3420346  0.27357404  0.17252692 
  1     1e-04  2.334369  0.3561022  0.25457211  0.13910683 
  1     1e-01  2.156721  0.4435387  0.07946054  0.04219603 
  3     0e+00       NaN        NaN          NA          NA 
  3     1e-04       NaN        NaN          NA          NA 
  3     1e-01       NaN        NaN

Comment: I never tried but is it possible to solve this problem in R-hadoop and use neuralnet pacakge for larger data sets ?